# How to Match with multiple values return with single value using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, match

In my equation like :-`10x+10y+5y+22y-10x //x,y,y,y,x` from string match function.I need a answer like `x,y` .It means the multiple value match to string return with single value.please give the suggestion.thanks

```js
var str ='10x+10y+10x-10y'
document.write(str.match(/[a-z]/g));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

see the answer x & y are dual time present.i need `x,y`..If multiple variables are present in equation it return with single variable only

Comment: Would you please give us an example?

Comment: Very unclear what you want. Do you want to identify the variables? Try `/([a-z])/g.exec('10x+10y+5y+22y-10x');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```js
var allVars='10x+10y+5y+22y-10x'.match(/[a-z]/g),
    uniqueVars = [];
$.each(allVars, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueVars) === -1) uniqueVars.push(el);
}); 
document.write(uniqueVars.join());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to figure out each unique variable in a given equation you can use a regex to filter out non-letter symbols

```
    String str = "10x+10y+5y+22y-10x";
    List<String> variables = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    while(m.find()) {
        String v = m.group();
        if (!variables.contains(v))  //unique part
                variables.add(v);
    }

    for (String variable : variables) {
        System.out.println(variable);
    }
```